# horizontal timeline transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline

can someone help me how to transform this vertical timeline to horizontal: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yinnette/XdQ5Y/

`<div class="timeline">`

thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. We're not a coding service. If you have trouble with a specific issue we're happy to help but general requests for code are off-topic here. What attempts have you made? Could you show us?

Comment: You are right man i haven't make any attempts....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need to make horizontal from this you can use rule

```
.timeline{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);/** Chrome & Safari **/
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /** Opera **/
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /** Firefox **/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XdQ5Y/348/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's **not** what the OP is looking for.